# Why onclick is being triggered twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a small piece of code on which I have been working:

All I want is to add an `active` class to label on click of the same element and leave the default behavior same.

I don't know why is the click event being triggered twice ??

```js
$('label.add-to-favourite').click(function(e){
  alert("here");
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.add-to-favourite span{
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #d2d6de;
}


.add-to-favourite:hover span, .add-to-favourite.active span {
    color: #CB3D3D;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul>
  <li>
    <label class="add-to-favourite">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
          <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-heart fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"  title="Add to Favourites" data-toggle="tooltip"></i>
      </span>
      <input type="checkbox" name="favourites[]" value="1">
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="add-to-favourite">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
          <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-heart fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"  title="Add to Favourites" data-toggle="tooltip"></i>
      </span>
      <input type="checkbox" name="favourites[]" value="2">
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: See [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element) regarding this behaviour: `For example, on platforms where clicking a checkbox label checks the checkbox, clicking the label in the following snippet could trigger the user agent to run synthetic click activation steps on the input element, as if the element itself had been triggered by the user: <label><input type=checkbox name=lost> Lost</label>
On other platforms, the behavior might be just to focus the control, or do nothing.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you click on the label, it triggers the checkbox`s click event.

But clicking on a label also automatically sends a click event to the associated input element, so this is treated as a click on the checkbox. Then event bubbling causes that click event to be triggered on the containing element, which is the label, so your handler is run again.

put the checkbox  outside the  label like so

```
<label></label>
<input type="checkbox">
```

**UPDATE** : you can also do as @Rejith R Krishnan suggested and set the click event handler on the checkbox and not the label

Comment: Rather than relocating the checkbox (which, if done as you've shown, blows the accessibility connection between them), I would suggest just changing which element the OP listens for `click` on.

Comment: Okay, i get it. but is there a way to do this without changing the HTML ??

Comment: yes you can do as @Rejith R Krishnan suggested and set the click event on the checkbox

Comment: @AngryCoder: Yes: Listen for `click` on the checkbox instead of the label.

Comment: Actually, Rejith suggested using `change`. That probably works reliably now. (Many years ago, it didn't on some browsers that didn't fire it until focus left the checkbox...)

Comment: If you want to keep the checkbox inside label, put e.preventDefault() on label's click event and manually change the insider checkbox state.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I agree it is not required, but it might be needed. As popular on many UI frameworks, the click on label triggers the checkbox click as well. It is just a requirement for better UE.

Comment: @wonderbell: "required" and "needed" are synonyms, something can't "not be required" and "be needed" simultaneously. On browsers, clicking the label fires the click on the checkbox. So there's no need, at all, for code handling the label click and toggling the checkbox value. That's the job of the browser. All we need do is handle the click on the checkbox, which (as indicated above) will fire whether the user clicks the checkbox itself or the associated label.

Answer (score 4):

Just define the target element type and this will work fine

```js
$('label.add-to-favourite').click(function(e){

 if(e.target.type=='checkbox'){
     alert("here");
     $(this).toggleClass('active');
   }

});
```

```css
.add-to-favourite span{
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #d2d6de;
}


.add-to-favourite:hover span, .add-to-favourite.active span {
    color: #CB3D3D;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul>
  <li>
    <label class="add-to-favourite">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
          <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-heart fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"  title="Add to Favourites" data-toggle="tooltip"></i>
      </span>
      <input type="checkbox" name="favourites[]" value="1">
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="add-to-favourite">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
          <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-heart fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"  title="Add to Favourites" data-toggle="tooltip"></i>
      </span>
      <input type="checkbox" name="favourites[]" value="2">
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
$('label.add-to-favourite').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $check = $(':checkbox', this);
    $check.prop('checked', !$check.prop('checked'));
    alert("here");
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

It will add class and also checks checkbox.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Mindaugas/71sefdhp/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the binding for the click and add `change` event binding to `checkbox`.

```js
$('label.add-to-favourite :checkbox').change(function(e){
  alert("here");
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.add-to-favourite span{
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #d2d6de;
}
.add-to-favourite:hover span, .add-to-favourite.active span {
    color: #CB3D3D;
}
.hide{display:none;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul>
  <li>
    <label class="add-to-favourite">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
          <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-heart fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"  title="Add to Favourites" data-toggle="tooltip"></i>
      </span>
      <input type="checkbox" class="hide" name="favourites[]" value="1">
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="add-to-favourite">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
          <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-heart fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"  title="Add to Favourites" data-toggle="tooltip"></i>
      </span>
      <input type="checkbox" class="hide" name="favourites[]" value="2">
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the case of event propagation.Try this

```
$('label.add-to-favourite').click(function(e){
  alert("here");
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
 e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I have already tried this. This will block the default behaviour of the element and checkbox wont be checked.

Answer (score 0):

> *I don't know why is the click event being triggered twice ??*

Well, I would say that `label` element is the parent element of the `checkbox`, So there is a connection between them. When you click the label click happens on checkbox too and event bubbles up, so causes in two alerts.

Either take the checkbox out of label or same then can be achieved though css only.

An example with little structure change.

```js
$('label.add-to-favourite').click(function(e) {
  alert("here");
  $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings(':checkbox').prop('checked', $(this).hasClass('active'))
});
```

```css
.add-to-favourite span {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #d2d6de;
}
.add-to-favourite:hover span,
.add-to-favourite.active span {
  color: #CB3D3D;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul>
  <li>
    <label class="add-to-favourite">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
          <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-heart fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"  title="Add to Favourites" data-toggle="tooltip"></i>
      </span>
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="favourites[]" value="1">

  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="add-to-favourite">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
          <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-heart fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"  title="Add to Favourites" data-toggle="tooltip"></i>
      </span>
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="favourites[]" value="2">

  </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

A CSS only solution.

```css
li{overflow:auto;}
.add-to-favourite span {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #d2d6de;
  float:left;
}
.add-to-favourite input[type="checkbox"]{
    margin-top:15px;
}
.add-to-favourite:hover span,
.add-to-favourite input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span{
  color: #CB3D3D;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul>
  <li>
    <label class="add-to-favourite">
      <input type="checkbox" name="favourites[]" value="1">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
          <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-heart fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"  title="Add to Favourites" data-toggle="tooltip"></i>
      </span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="add-to-favourite">
      <input type="checkbox" name="favourites[]" value="2">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
          <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-heart fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"  title="Add to Favourites" data-toggle="tooltip"></i>
      </span>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Remove the alert as well.

```
$('label.add-to-favourite').on("click",function(e){
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: I added alert just to show that the event is being triggered twice.